# Salesforce formula for multiple picklist values

Tags: formula-field, validation-rule, picklist

I am trying to write a formula where if Field- 'Status' contains picklist value as 'New','In-progress' or 'Escalated' then I want to make Field - Urgency to 'False'.
Can anyone please help me I tried the below code but for all status it is moving Field - Urgency to 'False'

```
IF(
 AND(
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'New')), 
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'In-Progress')), 
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Escalated'))
 )
 && NOW() > EndDate, 
 TRUE, 
 FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF( AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status , 'New')), NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status , 'In-Progress')), NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status , 'Escalated')))  && NOW() > EndDate, TRUE, FALSE)
```

In you're formula the issue is you're using `AND`. So it's make the correct condition out come as FALSE (by other 2 conditions) So Can you update it into `OR` as follows

```
(OR (TEXT(Status) == 'New', TEXT(Status) == 'In-progress', TEXT(Status) == 'Escalated') && NOW() > EndDate)
```

Hope it's helps.

Answer (score 0):

Raj is right in that you need an or but it wasn't complete to your question so I wanted to be more explicit.

```
IF(
 OR(
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'New')), 
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'In-Progress')), 
  NOT(ISPICKVAL(Status, 'Escalated'))
 )
 && NOW() > EndDate, 
 TRUE, 
 FALSE
)
```